# Unable to OAD new firmware on Sensor Tag CC2540

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I am using CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h framework to scan beacon. Where I need to update the firmware of beacon.

I am unable to detect the type of image A or image B in beacon.

I have refer link http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/8/82/OAD_for_CC254x.pdf for what is the type A images and B.

Comment: Is this an iBeacon or is this a BLE enabled device? iBeacons are treated differently and are not interacted with using CoreBluetooth. They are interacted with using CoreLocation.

Comment: UPDATE: re-read the title and realized this was about specifically the CC2540. This is not an iBeacon device, this is a programmable BLE embedded system. These implementation questions do not pertain to CoreBluetooth but to the implementation details and strategies provided by the TI stack.

Comment: What specifically is the "code from Radius Network" you have copied?  What are you expecting it to do?  I work for Radius, so may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The firmware in the beacon using the CC2540 must include the OAD Profile. If it is so, you activate the notifications in the first characteristic of the OAD service and you write `new byte[]{0}` and `new byte[]{1}` to it. You will receive a notification where the first two bytes (uint16) will have the value 0 or 1, depending on if the firmware currently has the version A or B respectively.